# is it possible to have group by in json data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

in my controller class and GetGroupedLogReport as JsonResult I return a List 
which has these properties : Name,State,...

in view i need to group this data by name and state :
here is the code:

```
 function SetReportGrid(pageNumber, extra) {
    $("#gvReportList tbody").html('');
    $('#pagination').html('');
    $.getJSON('/Report/GetGroupedLogReport', {
        fromDate: $('#FromDate').val() || "",
        toDate: $('#ToDate').val() || ""


    }, function (data) {
     //here

        }
                       gvReportList.init();
        });
    });
```

i need to get json data and group it by name and state then put it in the grid, how can i group it by?

here is data sample:

```
[Object { Id=563,Name="test",State="test"},{Id=543,Name="test2",State="test2"}]
```

Comment: Can you show more examples of the data result that you're expecting? We're not sure how you want to group this data without seeing examples.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with JSON. At the moment you access `data` you are working with a JavaScript object or array. There is no "group by" operation for these data types but I'm quite certain you can achieve what you want by iterating over the properties/elements.

Comment: your data sample isn't proper JSON

Answer (score 0):

JSON is only a data notation, a structure, it doesn't offer any kind of querying. One way of achieving that `group by` operation is to iterate over every element and memorizing the previous *key* and comparing if it has changed.

```
var key;
data.forEach(function(obj) {
   var k = obj.Name + ":" + obj.State;
   if (key !== k) {
       key = k;
       console.log("New group " + key);
   }
   console.log(obj.Id);
});
```

If you data isn't correctly ordered you may try this tool: [LINQ to JavaScript](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) which takes its inspiration from .NET LINQ. It enables querying like `select`, `where`, `order`, …

To conclude, if you can do this server-side you may get better (faster) results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just grouping by these two fields (Name and State) you can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library.

```
var data = [{ Id:563,Name:"test",State:"test"},{Id:543,Name:"test2",State:"test2"},
            {Id:544,Name:"test2",State:"test2"}, {Id:545,Name:"test2",State:"test2"}];

var res = alasql('SELECT Name, State FROM ? GROUP BY Name, State',[data]);
```

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/yrqj17yj/1/) in jsFiddle.