# Group by JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, grouping

I have a set of JSON array and I want the result to be grouped by the `"Id"` column. I will not use underscore.js for this, as this can't be used in our project. The only option is to do it with jQuery. My source array and expected results are below.

```js
var origObj = [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
               { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
               { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }]

var output = [{"1": [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
                     { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" }],
               "5": [{ "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }]}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried?

Comment: I have tried with for loops, but that didn't work. That's why I am seeking help.

Comment: I don't see any JSON here at all.  These are javascript array/object literals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get this done. Check this post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962158/909535 Extending on that this is what you would need

```js
var data= [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
        { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
        { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }];
        console.log(data.reduce(function(result, current) {
            result[current.Id] = result[current.Id] || [];
            result[current.Id].push(current);
            return result;
        }, {}));
```

Comment: Hey!! Cool man. That worked. I just assigned that to a variable instead of printing on console.

Comment: This seems to work great!. Is it compatible across all web browsers?

Comment: seems like it is.. in the latest browsers.. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Its Cool, But how can I apply with multiple key group by?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var origObj = [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
               { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
               { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }], output;
               
output = [origObj.reduce((a,c) => (a[c.Id]=(a[c.Id]||[]).concat(c),a) ,{})];

console.log(output);
```