# Group and filter items from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

I have an array called `items`, here is a sampel of the data inside the array:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"completed"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx222@gmail.com",
      "status":"completed"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx333@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx444@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx444@gmail.com",
      "status":"failed"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx555@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx555@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   }
]
```

I would like to group and filter items from my array. I have figured out that I could create a second array and push all items that match my criteria into that second array, but unsure how to achieve this.

Here are the criteria for grouping and filtering:

1. Group by `id` and `key` so that all records with the same `id` and `key` are grouped together and can be filtered in the next step. So here I could dynamically create arrays and they would look like this:

Array 1:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx111@gmail.com",
      "status":"completed"
   }
]
```

Array 2:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "key":"xxx222@gmail.com",
      "status":"completed"
   }
]
```

Array 3:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx333@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   }
]
```

Array 4:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx444@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx444@gmail.com",
      "status":"failed"
   }
]
```

Array 5:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx555@gmail.com",
      "status":"attempted"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx555@gmail.com",
      "status":"waiting"
   }
]
```

2. Above arrays should be filtered by `status`: if in an array I have either statuses `failed` or `completed` I do not want to consider this array anymore. Data from arrays that qualify could be pushed to my final array and I just need the `id` and `key` filed, I don't need to see the different statuses:

Final array:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx333@gmail.com"
   },
   {
      "id":"456",
      "key":"xxx555@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

So far I have tried this, but I am unable to get the desired results:

```js
  if(items.length >= 1) {
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        key = items[i]["key"];
        status = items[i]["status"];
        id = items[i]["id"];

        var arr=[];
        if(items[i]["key"]==key && items[i]["id"]==id) {
          arr.push(items[i]["key"])
          arr.push(items[i]["id"])
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `array3`?

Comment: check this answer for grouping the array : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893667/group-by-json-array-using-jquery

Comment: basically my final array is made up from arrays 3 and 5 as those had the correct statuses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group, filter and map the arrays with array with objects without `status`.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "completed" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx222@gmail.com", status: "completed" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx333@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx444@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx444@gmail.com", status: "failed" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx555@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx555@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }],
    keys = ['id', 'key'],
    unwanted = ['failed', 'completed'],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
            if (!r[key]) r[key] = [];
            r[key].push(o);
            return r;
        }, []))
        .filter(a => a.every(({ status }) => !unwanted.includes(status)))
        .map(a => a.map(({ status, ...rest }) => rest));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In really old JS

```js
var data = [{ id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx111@gmail.com", status: "completed" }, { id: "123", key: "xxx222@gmail.com", status: "completed" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx333@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx444@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx444@gmail.com", status: "failed" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx555@gmail.com", status: "attempted" }, { id: "456", key: "xxx555@gmail.com", status: "waiting" }],
    keys = ['id', 'key'],
    unwanted = ['failed', 'completed'],
    temp = {},
    result = [],
    i, j, k, key;

outer: for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    key = '';

    for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) key += data[i][keys[j]] + '|';

    if (temp[key] === null) continue;

    if (temp[key] === undefined) temp[key] = [];

    for (j = 0; j < unwanted.length; j++) {
        if (data[i].status !== unwanted[j]) continue;
        temp[key] = null;
        continue outer;
    }

    temp[key].push({ id: data[i].id, key: data[i].key });
}

for (k in temp) {
    if (temp[k]) result.push(temp[k]);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, and just double-checking, this will work in ecma3?

Comment: what is ecma 3?

Comment: for what do you need such old js version?