# How can i give each of the objects in my array their own key?

Tags: javascript, key, key-value

I am trying to change my data in such a way that each element of my object gets its own key. I reckon my question is fairly easy but I haven't figured out a way how to do this just yet.

The way my data is arranged right now:

```
[
  {
    "country name": "Qatar",
    "GDP": "140,649.2",
    "country code": "QAT"
  },
  {
    "country name": "MacaoSAR,China",
    "GDP": "139,767.3",
    "country code": "LUX"
  },
...
```

The way I would like my data to be arranged:

```
data: {    
    'QAT': {
         "country name": "Qatar",
         "GDP": "140,649.2",
       },
    'LUX': {
         "country name": "MacaoSAR,China",
         "GDP": "139,767.3",
       },
 ...
```

Please do not mind the different key-values pairs. I'm purely interested in how I can give my values within the `{}` brackets a key values, as is shown in the second example.

Comment: Just wrap your second example in `{}` and that should work for you.

Comment: I don't think i quite follow you, wrapping my second example doesn't really give each element a key-value?

Comment: Where is `startOfConflict` supposed to come from? or `fillKey`? or `name`?

Comment: I don't understand how you are logically going from the first example to the second. But the first example, your objects are in an array, so they don't have keys, in the second example the objects are in another object. So to give your object keys you need to put them inside an object.

Comment: Use objects not arrays. Objects have keys, (i.e. property names), arrays have positional locations.

Comment: These were examples from different data. It was only the structure i was interested in. I changed my question now so it's easier to understand. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Are you sure the "country code" will not repeat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by for json data using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961446/group-by-for-json-data-using-jquery)

Comment: While that possible duplicate says "using jquery[sic]" in the title, the answers do not depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for nonrecurring `"country code"` keys:

```
var arr = [    // exemplary array
    {
        "country name": "Qatar",
        "GDP": "140,649.2",
        "country code": "QAT"
    },
    {
        "country name": "MacaoSAR,China",
        "GDP": "139,767.3",
        "country code": "LUX"
    }
], rearranged = {};

arr.forEach(function(obj){
    var info = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => k === "country code" || (info[k] = obj[k]));
    rearranged[obj["country code"]] = info;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(rearranged, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "QAT": {
        "country name": "Qatar",
        "GDP": "140,649.2"
    },
    "LUX": {
        "country name": "MacaoSAR,China",
        "GDP": "139,767.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just send it as an object instead of an array like so...

```
{
  "NLD": {
    "fillKey": "conflict",
    "name": "2012 Northern Mali conflict",
    "startOfConflict": 2012
  },
  "LBY": {
    "fillKey": "conflict",
    "name": "2011– present Libyan factional fighting",
    "startOfConflict": 2011
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a problem, keys needs to be unique in the JSON, for example case keys may repeat, so you may lost some data while you parse, good to go with current structure or you can use numbers as keys.